# Speeding up file search with a shell

Tags: shell, find

Do you know any way to speed up file searching with a shell?

There is a lot of possibilities: `find`, `which`, `whereis`, ...

`find` seems to be the most useful, but it's very slow. Perhaps, I don't know the best way to use this functionality. How to find files faster?

Comment: Probably more appropriate for Super User

Answer (score 2):

`which` and `whereis` search for executables in your path - that's a pretty significant limitation if you're looking for something other than a program.

`find` does have lots of flexibility, but it executes the search when you run it without the help of indices.

`locate` works more quickly because it uses an indexed database of files. The down side to this is that it won't find files that are newer than the last database update. The db update is typically done regularly via a `cron` job.